# How to locate checkbox in gridview / <asp:templatefield> from another control on the same parent page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, checkbox, findcontrol

Attempting to use the code below to no avail - I cannot seem to locate the checkbox control.
Note: the grid does return the expected number of rows.
As indicated in the title I am trying to find the checkbox from another user control on the same parent page.

```
    Dim grid As GridView = CType(Me.Parent.FindControl(SearchControlID).FindControl("grdSearchResults"), GridView)

    For Each row As GridViewRow In grid.Rows
        Dim selectedRow As CheckBox = row.FindControl("chkRequestReference")
        If (selectedRow.Checked) Then
            rowSelected = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

A GridView is not a control container. It is a set of rows and columns. When you configure it you can set specific columns as CheckBoxes and you can make a direct reference to that column. For example:

`grid.Rows(RowNumber).Columns(ColumnName or ColumnIndex).Value`

- Nothing = Undefined
- 0 or False = Unchecked
- Anything else = Checked

Comment: Note that if your data comes from a Database the empty value can be DbNull intead of Nothing